# How to cross join 2 lists?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have two lists in Google Sheets. Looking to concatenate the results of both into one list, but quickly as both lists change semi-frequently.

I have a list of stores that rarely changes, and a list of products sold that changes monthly. Looking to combine them into unique values so I can look up off of them.

For example, I have list A with 2 items in it, and list B with 4 items in it. Looking to output:

```
A1_B1
A1_B2
A1_B3
A1_B4
A2_B1
A2_B2
A2_B3
A2_B4
```

Comment: see the second example given in the documentation for FLATTEN()  https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

For instance

```
=flatten(arrayformula(A1:A4&"_"&transpose(B1:B3)))
```

[image]

you can also try

```
=flatten(arrayformula(offset(A1,,,COUNTA(A:A))&"_"&transpose(offset(B1,,,COUNTA(B:B)))))
```

this formula will be adjust to the number of items